# Encoding video for android device

Tags: android, video, encoding, codec, progressive

What is the suggested video/audio codec for encoding videos for android devices which works on most of the devices?
I tried using H.264/AAC, but the output mp4 only works in android 2.2, devices running older os versions says "this video can not be played". I am using normal progressive playback (via http) i.e. no streaming servers etc. 
So how can I encode my videos (which video/audio codec and what settings) so that it works in normal progressive playback on most of the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the encoded video resolution does not exceed that of the device, typically 480x320 on first generation devices.

Sometimes if it does you will get audio only playback.  I have also seen video only playback when the audio parameters were incompatible.